# Connection refused on a Mapreduce job in a Hadoop cluster enviorment

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I've set up a 4 node Hadoop cluster with a master node and three data nodes. It all seems to run fine until I try to execute a map reduce job.

Jps (master-node):

```
[root@master logs]# jps
26967 SecondaryNameNode
25720 JobHistoryServer
26778 NameNode
27115 ResourceManager
27839 Jps
```

Jps (data-nodes):

```
[root@localhost ~]# jps
21872 DataNode
22257 Jps
21974 NodeManager
```

The yarn log file on the master node gives the following exception:

```
2018-05-22 21:59:10,376 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.RMAppImpl: Application application_1527018750538_0001 failed 2 times due to Error launching appattempt_1527018750538_0001_000002. Got exception: java.net.ConnectException: Call From NameNode/193.198.139.50 to localhost:41227 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor47.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:792)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:732)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1480)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy83.startContainers(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ContainerManagementProtocolPBClientImpl.startContainers(ContainerManagementProtocolPBClientImpl.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84.startContainers(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.amlauncher.AMLauncher.launch(AMLauncher.java:119)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.amlauncher.AMLauncher.run(AMLauncher.java:250)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:531)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:495)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:615)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:713)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2900(Client.java:376)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1529)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1452)
    ... 15 more
. Failing the application.
```

As far as I see it the problem is with the localhost:41227, since I've never specified anything like that in any of the configuration files, and the port number is a new one every time a try to run a new job, but obviously I'm not sure. Any advice or help is appreciated. Thanks

core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<!-- core-site.xml -->
<property>
<name>fs.defaultFS</name>
<value>hdfs://NameNode:9000/</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>io.file.buffer.size</name>
<value>131072</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
<value>yarn</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>mapreduce.jobhistory.address</name>
<value>NameNode:10020</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.address</name>
<value>NameNode:19888</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<!-- hdfs-site.xml -->
<property>
<name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
<value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_work/hdfs/namenode</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
<value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_work/hdfs/datanode</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.namenode.checkpoint.dir</name>
<value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_work/hdfs/namesecondary</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.replication</name>
<value>3</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.permissions</name>
<value>false</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.block.size</name>
<value>134217728</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

yarn-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
<value>NameNode</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.bind-host</name>
<value>0.0.0.0</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.bind-host</name>
<value>0.0.0.0</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
<value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce_shuffle.class</name>
<value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.log-aggregation-enable</name>
<value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs</name>
<value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_work/yarn/local</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs</name>
<value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_work/yarn/log</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir</name>
<value>hdfs://NameNode:9000/var/log/hadoop-yarn/apps</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the problem in the hostname of the Datanodes. 
Give a meaningful hostname to Datanodes other than localhost and restart the processes.

`Call From NameNode/193.198.139.50 to localhost:41227`

means it's trying to reach a random port of Datanode(localhost) from Namenode. Each node will listen to its loopback IP(127.0.0.1/localhost). It supposed to reach the data node but as per your config, it's trying to reach its own machine.

Can you also post your slaves file?

Comment: I've just managed to resolve that by changing the slaves host names into the same values as stated in the hadoop configuration for them. This is correct answer. Many thanks.